# how can I update the default text input box form , with a cell value from google sheets. I get the variable name and not the value

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, input, import

/* so the problem here is that the value is not passing through to the html display. WHAT COULD I BE POSSIBLY DOING WRONG??
My goal is to pass an item from google sheets to the html display.  Basically  to have the default value of an input box to come from a spreadsheets.
I do get an echo of the correct value from the logger, but having a problem representing the variable on the html end.

How would you pass a variable through to the html input box or can you post me to an example of that
*/

// FROM CODE.GS

```
  function getSheetData()  { 
    var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data'); 
    var dataRange = dataSheet.getDataRange();
    var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();  
  return dataValues;
}
function getFeedBack() {
 var app = SpreadsheetApp;
 var targetSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
 var currentDate = targetSheet.getRange(33,1).getValue();
 var lastUpdate =  currentDate;
 Logger.log(lastUpdate);

}
```

// HTML SECTION

```
<input type="text" id="dateID" value="" > 

<script>
  google.script.run.getFeedBack();
  document.getElementById("dateID").value = lastUpdate;
</script>
```

Comment: The html has to generate the request.

Comment: Thanks. Still working on it, no success... trying to import the value of  "lastUpdate" variable from the function.

Comment: Try my second attempt below.

Comment: You need to return data back through the withSuccessHandler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see PHP works hand in hand with JavaScript/HTML. So if you feel you have loaded the document data from googlesheets via Code.gs simply use this small script to grab the range to assign to the default value.

//define data PLACE IN TABLE OR FORM HEADER **** IMPORTANT *****
< ?var tableData = getSheetData();?>

//place in form variable
value="< ?= tableData[0][0] ?>"

//finally it should read something like this *** assuming data is in first cell (1,1); pls adjust to match cell you want to grab. *** remove space before question mark.

<input id="dateID" value="< ?= tableData[0][0] ?>"

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do it when you load the html

```
<input type="text" id="dateID" value="" > 

<script>
  window.onload=function(){
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(v){
      document.getElementById("dateID").value = v;  
    })
    .getV();
  }
  
</script>
```

You could also use templated html which is described in the guides section of the documentation for apps script

Try it this way:

These two functions are both Google Script and the html is integrated into the launch dialog function.  So it' hard to make a mistake.

```
function launchMyDialog() {
  let html='<input type="text" id="dateID" value="" ><script>window.onload=function(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(v){document.getElementById("dateID").value = v;}).getV();}</script>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),'Test');
}

function getV() {
  return "I'm v";
}
```

Just copy, paste, save and run.  Oh and you may have to authorize.

Comment: I see thanks again; however, the problems is that I have other scripts and html on the page.  Everything else works, except the call to the spreadsheet. At this point I feel need to recreate everything, tracing the variables closely.

Comment: So, I finally fixed it with one simple PHP scripts; value="<?= tableData[0][0] ?>" 
That did the trick inserting  into the form. PHP seemed to understand that the data was loaded, but javascript simply had problem managing the variables. This opens a whole new window for me. I can inject data wherever I want now. You had the right idea with HTML. Thanks for getting me thinking in the right direction.